# Sum time in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

How sum time in SQL my procedure return:

```
START   --    FINISH   ---   TOTAL
18:14:47    20:32:54    02:18:06
12:35:45    15:06:06    02:30:21
18:08:26    21:25:39    03:17:12
```

I need sum column TOTAL (08:05:40)

My stored procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[timeTotal] 
@userName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT

            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(HH,7,workStart),108) AS workStart,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(HH,7,workFinish),108) AS workFinish,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),workFinish - workStart,108) AS total


    FROM workTime
    WHERE userName = userName


END
```

I need get 08:05:40

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Also, a query is not a stored procedure (stored procedures start with `create procedure`.  I don't see how converting to strings can -- in any way -- help with this problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added stored procedura in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum time difference in hours, use the following:

```
SELECT
   (RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FromTime, ToTime)) / 60), 2)
  + ':' +
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, FromTime, ToTime)) % 60), 2)
  + ':' +
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, FromTime, ToTime)) % 60), 2)) 
AS TotalTime FROM AllocateRoom
```

Use the above in the stored procedure and it returns sum of time difference as follows:

```
01:20:20
```

Finally your expected data as follows:

```
;WITH DEMO(ID, FromTime, ToTime) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,FromTime,120) AS FromTime
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,ToTime,120) AS ToTime
    FROM (VALUES (1,'2016-09-03 18:14:47.000','2016-09-03 20:32:54.000')
                ,(2,'2016-09-03 12:35:45.000','2016-09-03 15:06:06.000')
    ) AS X(ID,FromTime,ToTime)
)
SELECT
    k.ID,
    k.FromTime,
    k.ToTime,
    DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND, k.FromTime, k.ToTime),CONVERT(TIME(0),'00:00:00',0)) AS TIME_DIFF,
    DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, k.FromTime, k.ToTime)) OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)
        ),CONVERT(TIME(0),'00:00:00',0)) AS TIME_SUM
FROM DEMO k;
```

Comment: Work fine for all row in table, but is it possible get TOP 7 (7 days) from table, after add TOP in stored procedure again get 01:20:20

Comment: Give a try. I hope, it'll work. Are you expecting to get last 7 days data?

Comment: I want get total last 7 or last 14 row (row = days), When put top in stored procedure no difference Top 7 or Top 14...

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow on this.

Answer (score 0):

use DATEDIFF() instead of subtraction to find the time different between 2 dates

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, workStart, workFinish) AS total
```

to display it in HH:MM:SS,

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, 0, DATEDIFF(SECOND, workStart, workFinish)),108) AS total
```